# ImageButton Android switch bg image

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me why this is not working?  I have no errors at all but simply doesnt work.

This actually used to work fine until I added the ScreenSwipe, now I cant figure out whats wrong.

Thanks

```
package com.sample.sample

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class PageOneFragment extends Fragment {

ImageButton btn1;
static int i = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.page1_layout, container, false);
btn1 = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.m1_btn);
return rootView;
}

public void setupPlayPauseButton1(View view) {
    btn1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.m1_btn);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i +=1;
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
            } else {
                btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

**EDIT**

Is this right?

```
package com.wepromoteme.brapp;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class PageOneFragment extends Fragment {

ImageButton btn1;
int i = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.page1_layout, container, false);
btn1 = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.m1_btn);


setupPlayPauseButton1(rootView);

return rootView;

}

private void setupPlayPauseButton1(View view) {
    btn1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.m1_btn);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i +=1;
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
            } else {
                btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

            }
        }   
    });
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "ScreenSwipe"? Is it the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) ?

Comment: `I have no errors at all but simply doesnt work`.  You need to think differently.  If you had no errors, it would work.  Start out by describing *exactly* what happens.  "Doesn't work" is a useless statement.  Also describe where and how you call `setupPlayPauseButton1`

Comment: The ScreenSwipe came from this tutorial and works a treat. http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html
Thanks

Comment: So it is indeed the **ViewPager**. Better to use the proper name ;)

Comment: @simon, apologies, having no errors means that my ide eclipse is no throwing up an errors, the app builds fine but the images do not change onclick as they used, yet its the same code but I have added the screen slide to it.  Thanks

Comment: `Also describe where and how you call setupPlayPauseButton1`

Comment: @nicopico, apologies, I'm a bit of a newb, I like to learn and get things right though so I appreciate you putting me right.  Thanks

Comment: If you don't call `setupPlayPauseButton1` it will never work.  Since it used to work, you must be calling it from somewhere which is why I ask where and how do you call it?

Comment: Thats a good point, now you have me stumped again as I havent removed any code that calls it :S

Comment: You might have used the `android:click` property of the `View` in your XML layout I guess

Comment: I didnt use android:click :p

Comment: @simon, I have added an edit to my code, eclipse doesnt flag any errors but it still doesnt work.  Can you see where I am going wrong?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens I have figured it out, I decided to let my brain have a few hours to rest as I think I got into a downward spiral of not being able to see that wood for the trees :P

Here is my code for anyone else who stumbles on the same problems I have.  This actually works:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class PageTwoFragment extends Fragment {

int i = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.page2_layout, container, false);

final ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.m1_btn);
final ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.m2_btn);
final ImageButton btn3 = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.m3_btn);
final ImageButton btn4 = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.m4_btn);
final ImageButton btn5 = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.m5_btn);

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        i +=1;
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
        } else {
            btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        }
    }
});

btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        i +=1;
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
        } else {
            btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        }
    }
});

btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        i +=1;
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            btn3.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
        } else {
            btn3.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        }

    }
});

btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        i +=1;
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            btn4.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
        } else {
            btn4.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        }

    }
});

btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        i +=1;
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            btn5.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
        } else {
            btn5.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            }       
    }
});

return rootView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not tell what "doesn't work", but I am willing to guess this is the cause: `static int i = 0;`

**static** here means that the value of `i` is shared by *all* instances of `PageOneFragment`.

If you are using static to keep the variable value when the screen is rotated, etc., you should use the fragment [`onSaveInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) method instead. You can find more information about this on the official documentation:
[Handling the Fragment Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle)

Comment: I dont want the screen to rotate at all and have set it not to.  I shall have a look at this now.  Thanks

Comment: So just remove `static` and you should be fine

Comment: Also as a personal taste I find it a bit irritating when apps refuse to rotate for no good reason :p

Comment: hahah, yeah me too sometimes but in this instance the app would not be very useful to anyone in portrait view.